# multiplying product price with the quantity inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sum, inner-join

I am trying to multiply the product price with the quantity in the while loop

```
$sql = "SELECT c.cart_id, c.product_id, c.company_id, c.quantity, c.unique_id, c.email, c.time, p.product_id, p.product_name, p.price, p.thumb_src, m.company_id, m.company_name FROM cart AS c INNER JOIN product AS p INNER JOIN company AS m WHERE c.product_id=p.product_id= c.company_id=m.company_id"; // Selecting the price from the product table
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $total = 0; // defining the total as 0
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cart_id, $product_id, $company_id, $quantity, $unique_id, $email, $time, $product_id, $product_name, $price, $thumb_src, $company_id, $company_name); // binding the parameter
                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){    
                $subtotal = $quantity * $price;
                $total += $subtotal
               }
```

And if in the DB only one record I get the correct output, however if I have two or more records my numbers totally messes up

Comment: You're also missing a ; after +=$subtotal

Comment: @clearshot66 oh this is not about this)) but thanks anyway ))

Comment: Mathematically it looks fine, show us what your actual output is and what you are looking for.

Comment: @clearshot66 see, in my cart table I have to different products, one with the quantity 1 and the second one with the quantity 1, prices are 8.00 and 9.00 and in the output I get 18.00 26.00, and as a total I get 26.00

Comment: @clearshot66 if you got teamviewer i could show you

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Put the summing into your query. PS Please read and act on [mcve].